# I can not build tailwindcss successfully

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am building a website with tailwindcss.
First,I run `npm init -y` to init my project,then I run `npm install tailwindcss` to install tailwindcss.
Then,I create `/src/input.css` and add this content to this file.

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I run `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./public/style.css` to generate style.css file.  But my
style.css file only have 500 lines.I think It should have 2w lines. Then I link to this file in my `index.html`.I can not use all taiwindcss style,such as,`container`,`mx-auto`.
How can I use tailwindcss style in my html?Please help me.Thanks a lot.
this is my file structure

```
public
|_index.html
|_style.css
src
|_input.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Using `Tailwind-cdn`

###### `<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <script>
      tailwind.config = {            //  Your tailwind.config.js here
        theme: {
          extend: {
            colors: {
              clifford: "#da373d",
            },
          },
        },
      };
    </script>
    <style type="text/tailwindcss">
      @layer utilities {
        .content-auto {
          content-visibility: auto;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold text-red-700">Hello world!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output

[image]

#### 2. Using `tailwind CLI` or `PostCSS`

###### 1. Know about your file structure. Use:

```
public
|_ tailwind_base.css 
    File from which the output.css is produced
     @tailwind base;
     @tailwind components;
     @tailwind utilities;
|_ output.css
src
|_ index.html   
   Link with the output.css using 
    <link href="../public/output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

###### Watch it as

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./public/tailwind_base.css -o ./public/output.css --watch
```

###### Specify your `html/js` in `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Use `tailwindcss classes` happily in your `index.html` file

---

##### Mistake in your [github link](https://%20github.com/changzheng0101/tailwindcss-test):

Your html is inside `dist` folder. But you are specifying path to `src` folder

Change

```
content: ["./src/**.*.{html,js}"]
```

to

```
content: ["./dist/**/*.{html,js}"]
```

##### Alternatively

Place your html file inside the src and link properly with the output.css
and use

```
content: ["./src/**.*.{html,js}"]
```

Refer https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Comment: thanks a lot!This works.But in this way,I can't customize my style.I want to use a `tailwind.config.js` to get my own settings.

Comment: I follow the step in the webiste.But I met the same problem.This is my source code https://github.com/changzheng0101/tailwindcss-test.git .I think I miss some css code in `output.css`.

Comment: I change the link. please look at this https://github.com/changzheng0101/tailwindcss-test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250822/discussion-between-smile-and-krishna-acharya).

Comment: I slove this!thanks a lot.I have typo in my github file.`content: ["./dist/**.*.{html,js}"]` shuold be `content: ["./dist/**/*.{html,js}"]`.Please change it in your answer so that others will not be confused.

Comment: Happy to hear it worked ! Thank you for letting me the error

Answer (score 3):

First, you to create react app after creating react now you need to install tailwind in your app by the following methods are following below.

1.npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer 2.npx tailwindcss init -p 3.After running above the code in terminal.You need to open tailwind.config.cjs and write the following code in content section .

content: [ "./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", ], 4.Open your main CSS in react app and put following code in your CSS

@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;

5.After doing this you need to start your react app with following code.

npm run dev

Answer (score 0):

have you make a file tailwind.config.js? if not, you should make that file first and paste this code

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

after that, you link to ./style.css

Comment: I have this file,but It still doesnt work.